# Do there exist nonconstant holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on the open unit disk such that $e^{f(z)}+e^{g(z)}=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from an old qualifying exam that I was trying to solve for practice:

Prove or disprove that there exist nonconstant holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on the open unit disk $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ such that $e^{f(z)}+e^{g(z)}=1$ for all $z\in D$?

My initial thought was to show it is true on the real line and then use the uniqueness principle.  But the examples I came up with on the real line use logarithms, which will not be continuous when I consider them as functions on the unit disk.

Since this is for practice, I was hoping only for hints and suggestions instead of complete answers. Thank you!

Comment: "uniqueness principle" would only apply if you had existence on an open set, and the real line is not open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I thought it was existence on a set with a nonisolated point, for which the real line would work.

Comment: I think that's not right - to be honest uniqueness principle cannot show existence either way! It would show uniqueness

Comment: In practice, the idea of using the uniqueness is unlikely to be helpful. You would have to be in a scenario where (a) it was very obvious that $f,g$ are holomorphic on the whole disk, but (b) the computation to show the above formula is only "easy" to do on $\mathbb{R}$, which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @ John Fernley Uniqueness theorem for holomorphic functions states that if they are equal on a set with a limit point they are equal on the entire domain http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Uniqueness_properties_of_analytic_functions. Real line is more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** it is fine to use logarithms as long as they are applied to values from a set that doesn't circle the origin. Suppose you picked some $f(z)$, than you need to solve $e^{g(z)}=1-e^{f(z)}$. One solution is obviously $g(z)=\text{Ln}(1-e^{f(z)})$, where $\text{Ln}$ is the [principal branch of the logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) with the cut along the negative half-axis. So you need to make sure that $f(z)$ maps the unit disk into a region, which $1-e^{z}$ then maps into something not crossing the negative half-axis. A judiciously chosen Möbius transformation should do the trick.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just chose $g(x)$ such that $e^{g(z)}\neq 1$ for all $z$ in the unit disk. Then 
$f(x)=\ln (1-e^{g(x)})$ under some well defined branch of the log function.

Comment: $e^{g(z)}\neq 1$ is not enough. If $1-e^{g(z)}$ maps the disk onto some annulus surrounding $0$ there won't be globally defined branch of logarithm on it even if it misses $0$ itself.

Comment: @Conifold: If you have a nowhere-vanishing holomorphic function $h(z)$ in a simply connected region $U$ then you can define a branch of $\log h(z)$ in $U$. Here $U$ is the unit disc, which is clearly simply connected, and $h(z)$ is $1 - e^{g(z)}$.

Comment: I was thinking of something like $z^2$ mapping a simply connected piece of annulus onto the whole annulus, there wouldn't be a branch of $\ln$ on that.

Comment: Fix a point $z_{0}$ in $U$. You can define a branch by letting $L(z) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{h'(w)}{h(w)} \ dw + c_{0}$, where $\gamma$ is a path in $U$ connecting $z$ to $z_{0}$ (this is well-defined by the simple connectivity assumption), and $c_{0}$ is chosen so that $e^{c_{0}} = h(z_{0})$. It's then easy to verify that $e^{L(z)} = h(z),$ e.g. see Stein and Shakarchi's 'Complex Analysis,' end of Ch. 3. This isn't a "branch" in the normal sense as when you're considering all of $\mathbb{C}$, but the log is still well-defined in $U$.

Comment: Look up Monodromy theorem.

Comment: The answer refers to "well defined branch of the log", which as you admit is incorrect, and monodromy theorem, etc., is unnecessarily complicated and probably above the head of the OP.

Comment: It's not "incorrect." You can define a holomorphic function $L(z)$ in $U$ such that $1 - e^{g(z)} = e^{L(z)}$, which is all you need. When you're looking at behavior on $U$ you don't need to worry about all of $\mathbb{C}$ (in all of $\mathbb{C}$ the identity likely won't hold, but that doesn't matter for the problem). There's an obvious sense in which $L(z)$ behaves as the logarithm of $h(z)$ in $U$, so we can say that it determines a "branch" of the log of $h(z)$ in $U$.

Comment: Sure, but $\ln$ in the answer is not a "well defined branch of the log" as commonly understood, and without the explanations buried in the comments the "reasoning" (or rather lack thereof)  is misleading.

Comment: To clarify, I said originally that it's a well-defined branch of $\log h(z)$ in $U$. But yes, you're right that it should be pointed out that we're talking about $\log h(z)$ rather than $\log z$.